# can I put a scrollable text field on a uialertview?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uialertview

I am needing to alert something for an answer for a trivia game iOS app I am writing. I have an alert view that pops up and shows a scrollable uitextview...is Apple going to ding me for that? What are my options for showing large amounts of text in my alert?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that showing UITextView is ok. Moreover it seems that Apple actually does the same thing - if you try to display very long text in UIAlertView then it will be displayed in scrollable UITextView automatically

**P.S.** and it also uses UITableView instead of buttons if you set too many button names.